# Xamarin.Forms.Maps in CarouselView: Route not shown directly

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.maps, xamarin.forms.carouselview

I have a problem with displaying a route in a map on a carouselView.

## Setup

I have the carouselview in my VireModel binded to a cotentview

```
        private ContentView carousel;
        public ContentView Carousel
        {
            get { return carousel; }
            set
            {
                if (carousel != value)
                {
                    carousel = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Carousel");
                }
            }
        }
```

I give it the following contentViews as items

```
        private void InitializeCarousel()
        {
            Carousel = new ContentView()
            {
                Content = CarouselView()
            };
        }

        private CarouselView CarouselView()
        {
            ContentView[] items = CarouselItems();


            CarouselView carouselView = new CarouselView()
            {

                ItemsSource = items,
                IndicatorView = indicatorView,
                ItemTemplate = viewDataTemplate
            };

            return carouselView;
        }

        private ContentView[] CarouselItems()
        {
            ContentView[] items = new ContentView[5] 
            {
                 MapView(), SpeedView(), PaceView(), HeightView(), StepLengthView() 
            };


            return items;

        }
```

*MapView()* is implemented like this:

```
        private ContentView MapView()
        {
            
            Polygon route = new Polygon
            {
                StrokeWidth = 8,
                StrokeColor = Color.FromHex("#1BA1E2"),
                Geopath =
                {
                    new Position(47.6368678, -122.137305),
                    new Position(47.6368894, -122.134655),
                    new Position(47.6359424, -122.134655),
                    new Position(47.6359496, -122.1325521),
                    new Position(47.6424124, -122.1325199),
                    new Position(47.642463,  -122.1338932),
                    new Position(47.6406414, -122.1344833),
                    new Position(47.6384943, -122.1361248),
                    new Position(47.6372943, -122.1376912)
                }
            };

            MapSpan span = new MapSpan(new Position(47.6368678, -122.137305), 0.02, 0.02);
            
            Map map = new Map(span)
            {
                HasScrollEnabled = false,
                HasZoomEnabled = false,
            };

            map.MapElements.Add(route);

            ContentView view = new ContentView()
            {
                Content = map
            };

            return view;
        }
```

## Problem

The problem is that if the page is open in the app the map is zoomed out completly. If I swipe trough the carousel on time completly I see the Route and the MapSpan is correct.

1. First:

[image]

2. After swiping trough the carousel completly

[image]

## Edit

here is a gif of the problem

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please add `map.MoveToRegion(mapSpan);` in your `MapView`'s method.

```
 private ContentView MapView()
        {
            
            Polygon route = new Polygon
            {
                StrokeWidth = 8,
                StrokeColor = Color.FromHex("#1BA1E2"),
                Geopath =
                {
                    new Position(47.6368678, -122.137305),
                    new Position(47.6368894, -122.134655),
                    new Position(47.6359424, -122.134655),
                    new Position(47.6359496, -122.1325521),
                    new Position(47.6424124, -122.1325199),
                    new Position(47.642463,  -122.1338932),
                    new Position(47.6406414, -122.1344833),
                    new Position(47.6384943, -122.1361248),
                    new Position(47.6372943, -122.1376912)
                }
            };

            MapSpan span = new MapSpan(new Position(47.6368678, -122.137305), 0.02, 0.02);
            
            Map map = new Map(span)
            {
                HasScrollEnabled = false,
                HasZoomEnabled = false,
            };

            map.MapElements.Add(route);
           
            ContentView view = new ContentView()
            {
                Content = map
            };
            map.MoveToRegion(mapSpan);
            return view;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I did not had time to try it out till today.  As a remark: Is should bei `map.MoveToRegion(span)`. Unfurtunately this is not solving the problem. I also tried to but the command over the `ContentView view = ...` part.

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe it is a problem because I do not debug on a real android phone?

Comment: No, you can debug it in your device or android emulator. If you do not know how to use it, it is article about it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/map#move-the-map

Comment: At the moment I am using the android emulartor and it is working good. Thanky for the link I already worked myself trough the documentation however I do not find out how I can solve my problem.

Comment: Do you mean that work in your emulator? But it is not work in your device?

Comment: No, unfurtunately it is not working in the emulator and is not working on my device.

Comment: Could you share a demo that could reproduce your issue?

Comment: I try to make one in the next days. At the moment I am working on some other, more important thinks.

Comment: Ok, you can post here when you feel free.

Comment: It is hard for me tro recreate the probelm as I would have to register a new project at my google account. I added a gif that visualizes the problem. I hope this helps.